# Prove such $f$ is continuous and surjective

Tags: analysis

The function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ has a property such that $\lvert x-y-(f(x)-f(y))\rvert\leq\frac{1}{3}\lvert x-y\rvert$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$. I am asked to prove it is continuous and surjective but I have no idea how to do that. May anyone help?

Comment: Do you know the mathematical definitions of continuity and surjectivity? If so, have you tried to test these properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=x+\epsilon$. Then you have
$$
|-\epsilon-(f(x)-f(x+\epsilon)|\le |\epsilon|/3.
$$
or
$$
2|\epsilon|/3\le |f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)|\le 4|\epsilon|/3
$$
So in the limit $\epsilon\to 0$ you conclude
$$
|f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)|\to 0
$$
which is continuity. As for surjectivity, fix $x=x_0$. From the second formula above it follows that
$$
|f(x_0+\epsilon)|\ge -|f(x_0)|+2|\epsilon|/3,
$$
that is, there are images of $f$ outside of an arbitrarily large ball (of radius $-|f(x_0)|+2|\epsilon|/3$). Given that $f$ is continuous, that implies surjectivity (the union of balls is the whole space).

Comment: The second part only proves that the image is an unbounded subset of $\Bbb R^n$: however it may not be the whole space.

Comment: Both parts deal with $\mathbb{R}$, not $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that
\begin{alignat*}{1}
|f(x)-f(y)| & =|x-y-(f(x)-f(y))-(x-y)|\\
 & \le|x-y-(f(x)-f(y))|+|x-y|\\
 & \le\frac{1}{3}|x-y|+|x-y|=\frac{4}{3}|x-y|
\end{alignat*}

for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Thus, $f$ is a Lipschitz function and hence it is **continuous**.

Since $|x-y|-|f(x)-f(y)|\le|x-y-(f(x)-f(y))|$, we have $|f(x)-f(y)|\ge\frac{2}{3}|x-y|$ and this shows that $f$ is **injective**.

If $f(x_n)\to y$, then
$$
|x_n - x_m| \le \frac32 |f(x_n)-f(x_m)|\le \frac32 |f(x_n)-y| + \frac32 |y-f(x_m)|
$$
for all $m,n\ge1$. Hence, $(x_n)$ is Cauchy sequence, therefore, $x_n \to x$ for some $x\in\mathbb R^n$. Thus, $f(x)=y$. So we've just shown that $f(\mathbb R^n)$ is **closed**.

Brouwer's theorem on invariance of domain (see Theorem 1.1.9 in **L. Conlon**, *Differentiable Manifolds*, $2^\mathrm{nd}$ed., 2001, Birkhauser.) shows that $f(\mathbb R^n)$ is open and since it is non-empty connected subset of $\mathbb R^n$ we must have $f(\mathbb R^n)=\mathbb R^n$, thus, $f$ **surjective**.

Note: Couldn't find an elementary argument shows that $f$ is **open**!